# Finding selector position within parent/set with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to find out at what position in terms of `parent > child:eq(n)` the current selector sits, so that I can use `.insertAfter()` and `.insertBefore()` to properly move the element around within it's nest.

I've looked through several parts of the jQuery doc, but I've yet to find a function that gives the current selector's position within it's parent relevant to nest structure (as oppose to dimensional position when can be found through `.postion()`).

Any points to the right function for this, or a good way to move around elements in the following structure using jQuery would be greatly, greatly, greatly appreciated ;)!

```
<ul data-submenu="1" class="sub-menu">
     <li>Text Module</li>
     <li>Feature Module</li>
     <li>Feature Module</li>
</ul>
```

(I need to move each `<li>` element around within the `<ul>` parent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're looking for the [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index) method, which, if provided with no parameters, returns the elements position relative to it's siblings.

```
var index = $(this).index();
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use `$.each()`:

```
$('.sub-menu').children('li').each(function(index) {
  console.log('This is the ' + index + ' li element.');
});
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why `.each()`. I thought that was a loop function?

Comment: You said "move around elements in the following structure", which leads me to believe you are looping over the list items within the unordered list. If you're explicitly moving the ith element to the jth position, then I would go for the `index()` method as @Matt suggested. I might not fully understand the question.

Comment: Ah, apologies, I should have clarified better. They're being explicitly moved a set number of nodes in the structure, e.g. 1 or 2 up or down, on click not in collective :).